# How can I switch between three pages in Angular 7 using ngIf?

Tags: angular

I am trying to switch bewteen 3 pages in my Angular 7 app and I have been able to switch between two pages, but my messages page loads in the documents section whenever I click it.

As stated above, I have tried using NgSwitch, but I haven't learned how to properly use that statement yet (I am going through a tutorial on Udemy and this is as far as I have gotten.) So I have used `*ngIf="loadedFeature !== 'contacts'` and it sort of works, but with this code added:

```
<cms-documents *ngIf="loadedFeature !== 'contacts'"></cms-documents>
<cms-message-list *ngIf="loadedFeature !== 'contacts'"></cms-message-list>
```

it loads documents and messages on the other two pages and not contacts.

This is part of my HTML code

```
<cms-header (selectedFeatureEvent)=switchView($event)></cms-header>
 <div class="row" style="margin-left:18%;">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <cms-documents *ngIf="loadedFeature !== 'contacts'"></cms-documents>
    <cms-message-list *ngIf="loadedFeature !== 'contacts'"></cms-message-list>
    <cms-contacts *ngIf="loadedFeature == 'contacts'"></cms-contacts>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cms-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'cms';
  loadedFeature = 'contacts';

  switchView(selectedFeature: string) {
   this.loadedFeature = selectedFeature;
  }
}
```

This is my header HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WeLearn CMS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelected('documents')">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelected('message-list')">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelected('contacts')">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">User <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

And finally, this is my header.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cms-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Output() selectedFeatureEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onSelected(selectedEvent: string) {
    this.selectedFeatureEvent.emit(selectedEvent);
  }
}
```

When I run this code with `ng serve`, I am able to navigate successfully between two pages. But when I click on messages or documents, nothing happens. but messages is loaded with the documents file vice versa. I need to have it so when I click on Documents, it loads documents. When I click on messages, it loads messages and not documents or contacts. What can I do to successfully switch between 3 pages and not have Documents, Messages and Contacts pages loaded at the same time? This is what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF8jx.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `ngSwitch` correctly, do it like this:

```
<cms-header (selectedFeatureEvent)=switchView($event)></cms-header>
 <div class="row" style="margin-left:18%;">
   <div class="col-md-12" [ngSwitch]="loadedFeature">
    <cms-documents *ngSwitchCase="'documents'"></cms-documents>
    <cms-message-list *ngSwitchCase="'message-list'"></cms-message-list>
    <cms-contacts *ngSwitchCase="'contacts'"></cms-contacts>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Angular doc on ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch).

Basically, you place an `[ngSwitch]="loadedFeature"` directive on the container element, and `*ngSwitchCase="'string-value'"` directives on the child elements you want to toggle. When `loadedFeature` will be equal to `contacts`, the `<cms-contacts>` cmoponent will show and not the others.

You can also add an `ngSwitchDefault` with no argument to tell angular which component to display if there is no match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, when I tested the code that you have provided, the application is unable to load the pages when I put in `ngSwitch`.

Comment: Can you try with ticks around the string values, e.g., *ngSwitchCase="'contacts'"? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I did try, but I was able to solve it. I just needed to make my ngIf statements equal to the selector.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. I appreciate it. Should I write how I solved it as an answer to my own question?